# Querying Global fields using CraftQL and Gatsby JS

Tags: craft3

I am using Craft in headless mode with the CraftQL plugin. My front end is built using Gatsby JS.

I am able to query entries and output the data to my templates, however Global fields are not available. Here is my code:

```
// gatsby-config.js
plugins: [
  {
        resolve: `gatsby-source-craftcms`,
        options: {
            endpoint: `http://cms.local/api`,
            token: `REDACTED`,
            query: `{
                globals: globals {
                    contact {
                        address
                    }
                },
                home: entries(section:[home]) {
                    id
                    title
                    ... on Home {
                        subHeading
                        intro
                        ctaButton {
                            ... on CtaButtonButton {
                                __typename
                                text
                                linkUrl
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
// etc
```

And then in my template:

```
export const query = graphql`
  query {
    home {
        title
        subHeading
        intro
        ctaButton {
            text
            linkUrl
        }
    }
    globals {
        contact {
            address
        }
    }
  }
`
```

In my console I get:

```
error  Cannot query field "globals" on type "Query"
```

If I remove the `globals` from the query I can successfully build and output `data.home.title`.

I've tried using the CraftQL browser in the CMS and I can successfully query globals:

[image]

I'm confident I'm missing something but can find nothing in the docs for [Gatsby-Source-Craft](https://github.com/gusnips/gatsby-source-craftcms/blob/master/README.md) or [CraftQL](https://github.com/markhuot/craftql).

Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong here??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So having spoken to the maker of CraftQL yesterday, my mistake was assuming I needed to use `gatsby-source-craftcms` as my source plugin. In actual fact, the standard [`gatsby-source-graphql`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-source-graphql/) was much better and more abstract, meaning you don't need to construct giant graphQL queries in the `gatsby-config`. Also the docs for it are much better explained.

now my `gatsby-config.js` looks like this:

```
plugins: [
    {
        resolve: `gatsby-source-graphql`,
        options: {
    typeName: "Craft",
    fieldName: "craft",
    // Url to query from
    url: "http://cms.local/api",
    // HTTP headers
    headers: {
      Authorization: `bearer ACCESSTOKENHERE`,
    }
        },
    },
```

and my query looks like this

```
{
  craft {
    globals {
      contact {
        address
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which is much more sane and closer the the normal Twig API

You can view the [Twitter exchange here](https://twitter.com/markhuot/status/1059850263706640385)

Answer (score 1):

In looking at this, the first thing I notice is that your query has a field called `globals`, but your error has the singular `global`.

If you open Gatsby’s GraphiQL instance (`http://localhost/8000/___graphql` in develop mode), can you see the Craft CMS data in the docs? That might help zero in on the query to use in Gatsby.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi and thanks for the response. That was a typo. I was trying all sorts to get this working and copy/pasted from the wrong terminal. I updated my question. 

I can see the Craft CMS data for `home` but not `globals`. I've made a reduced test with just 1 template and querying only home and globals and same outcome. I'm doing/not doing something... Oh well. I'll keep plugging away. Thanks again!